# Building custom interface in Android using Graphics

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I want you to direct me to good links or give me the basic elements that I have to study and read about to be able to build a custom user interface in android.
What I  mean by custom is that the interface will contain buttons that are images not a regular android button.
Also I have to generate custom buttons on the fly based on user action and those generated buttons should have events associated with them.

Comment: Buttons, buttoms or bottums?...

Comment: depends if your mother tongue is English or jewesh
يا وجه البطمة

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic info about buttons [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)

To use image for a button you need an [android.widget.ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html). Example of drawable selector (put it in  res/drawable/):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

So you can use different images for various states.
To generate buttons on the fly you can define base layout with any layout manager (FrameLayout, RelativeLayout, LinearLayout), find it by id (findViewById()) within your Activity and make it visible:

```
public void createContainerForImageView() { 
    LinearLayout container = new LinearLayout(this);  
    container.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
    container.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL); 

    ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
    Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sc01);
    int width=200;
    int height=200;
    Bitmap resizedbitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height, true);    
    img.setImageBitmap(resizedbitmap);

    container.addView(img); // or you can set the visibility of the img
}
```

Hope this helps.